# reading multiple sheets from excel to matlab

Tags: excel, matlab

I am trying to read an excel file with multiple sheets into matlab. All the sheets have the same headings and I want the data from each sheet to be merged together so that I can plot selected columns.

I am new to matlab so any sample codes will be extremely helpful.
Thank you
T

Comment: Can you post what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [xlsfinfo function](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/xlsfinfo.html) together with the [xlsread function](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/xlsread.html) in order to read your sheets dynamically. No matter how many sheets your file will contain, this approach will grant an output in the form of a [table](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/tables.html) with properly named column headers and with sheet datasets stacked on the top of each other:

```
[~,sheets] = xlsfinfo('data.xlsx');

data = [];

for i = 1:numel(sheets)
    if (i == 1)
        [data_curr,headers] = xlsread('data.xlsx',i);
    else
        data_curr = xlsread('data.xlsx',i);
    end

    data = [data; data_curr];
end

data = array2table(data,'VariableNames',headers);
```

Let's suppose that your file contains the following sheets:

```
         SHEET A
-------------------------
Header1  Header2  Header3
   6       15        8
   1        8        3
   2        2        4
  13       11        8
   1        7       14
   4       14        4
  17       10        6

         SHEET B
-------------------------
Header1  Header2  Header3
  14        4        6
  12        1       13
   8       16        7
  11        6        5
   3       11        5
   7       14       11
   7        2       11
```

The final output will be:

```
data =

    Header1    Header2    Header3
    _______    _______    _______

     6         15          8     
     1          8          3     
     2          2          4     
    13         11          8     
     1          7         14     
     4         14          4     
    17         10          6     
    14          4          6     
    12          1         13     
     8         16          7     
    11          6          5     
     3         11          5     
     7         14         11     
     7          2         11
```

Comment: Hiya, I forgot to respond to this but it worked perfectly! Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Read the sheets into tables, then concatenate the tables:

```
T1 = readtable('myfile.xls', 'Sheet',1);
T2 = readtable('myfile.xls', 'Sheet',2);

T = [T1;T2]  % Make a new table T by adding T2 to the end of T1
```